# Adwhirl advertisement fetching from Admob

Tags: ios, admob, adwhirl

I integrated Adwhirl into my IOS app, opened an account and included the sdk of Admob to my project. I have set up all the things that I had to. The problem is when I run my application I don't see any ads displaying on my screen. However, in adMob site, my requests are increasing whenever I request from my phone. How can I display my ad on the screen?

P.S: When I run adwhirl in test mode it works fine.

Comment: Have you implemented `-(void)adWhirlDidReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView` ? What is the value of adWhirlView.adExists at this point?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I have implemented it, The delegate method returned by request is -(void)adWhirlDidFailToReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView usingBackup:(BOOL)yesOrNo . I have setup all the things that are required as like as its explanation. However It's not working :S